# JQuery click event doesn't fire on Android?

Tags: android, jquery, mobile, google-analytics

I have an icon on a mobile website that I want to attach an event to whenever someone touches it. The icon's link has an href with a `tel` prefix, so it pops up the dialer application on your phone when you touch it. Before that happens, I want to register the touch as an event with Google Analytics. Here's the code I have embedded into the page:

```
$("a[href^='tel']").bind('click touchstart', (function(event){
    pageTracker._trackEvent("Mobile", "Click", "Telephone", 75, true);
}));
```

The touch is registered correctly on iOS devices, but not Android, Windows Phone, or my desktop computer running Firefox. Is there a way that works for all mobile devices?

Comment: You don't *need* the parentheses surrounding the anonymous function. I don't think this will solve your problem, but... Save yourself the hassle and the future "syntax" error and don't do that. `:)`

Comment: Noted. Haha I think that's just a remnant of me trying to debug it. It definitely wasn't working without that.

Comment: Are you sure all of those devices support `touchstart`? What demonstrates it's *not* working? (This is probably obvious, but still). Is it possible to log the click in addition to the `pageTracker` call? Also (nitpicky squared) you don't need quotes around a term in a selector unless it has a space. `:D`

Comment: I can tell it's not working by going into my profile on Google Analytics. After I touch the icon on my iPhone, the call to `_trackEvent()` causes the touch to be registered in the "Events" section on GA. (It appears 5-10 minutes later due to processing by Google) When I look at all events and I drill down to Operating System, they all say "iOS".

Also, I added an `alert()` after the `pageTracker` call and the message box did appear, but again only on iOS.

Comment: You have to triangulate the problem. Is it firing at all (and it's a `pageTracker` issue)? Is `touchstart` supported by anything but iOS? Can another touch event and/or selector be tried to narrow down the issue? I don't see anything explicitly wrong with your code. The only caveat may be your attribute selector, `href` is wonkish.